# How to load HTML into JS using SystemJs

Tags: angular, deployment, gulp, systemjs

I'm new to Angular 2. I'm trying to make deployment dist. Following this [flow](https://github.com/Anjmao/angular2-production-workflow) I managed to build index.html and js files, but on run it shows:

```
1475654341064.vendor.bundle.js:5803 XMLHttpRequest cannot load app/app.component.html
```

and

```
... login/login.component.html
```

so I assume I should load html from this files to js. How to make this in gulp?

Comment: if am not wrong, I believe the above error is related to "not found"

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin - https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template.
It will inline templates into component metadata